# Pygame - Changing the speed of the sprite sheet

Tags: pygame

So my sprite sheet is transitioning too fast for my liking and I want it to move a little slower.  Ideally, I want my character to move slowly (a nice walking pace) but right now he shifts left and right and moves upward really fast.
Here is my code:

```
import pygame

class Serge(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.sheet = pygame.image.load('picture.png')
        self.sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 150))
    self.image = self.sheet.subsurface(self.sheet.get_clip())
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.topleft = position
    self.frame = 0
    self.left_states = { 0: (0, 150, 100, 150), 1: (100, 150, 100, 150), 2: (300, 150, 100, 150) }
    self.right_states = { 0: (0, 300, 100, 150), 1: (100, 300, 100, 150), 2: (300, 300, 100, 150) }
    self.down_states = { 0: (0, 450, 100, 150), 1: (100, 450, 100, 150), 2: (300, 450, 100, 150) }
    self.up_states = { 0: (0, 0, 100, 150), 1: (100, 0, 100, 150), 2: (310, 0, 100, 150) }

def get_frame(self, frame_set):
    self.frame += 1
    if self.frame > (len(frame_set) - 1):
        self.frame = 0
    return frame_set[self.frame]

def clip(self, clipped_rect):
    if type(clipped_rect) is dict:
        self.sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(self.get_frame(clipped_rect)))
    else:
        self.sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(clipped_rect))
    return clipped_rect

def update(self, direction):
    if direction == 'right':
        self.clip(self.left_states)
        self.rect.x += 1
    if direction == 'left':
        self.clip(self.right_states)
        self.rect.x -= 1
    if direction == 'up':
        self.clip(self.up_states)
        self.rect.y -= 1
    if direction == 'down':
        self.clip(self.down_states)
        self.rect.y += 1

    if direction == 'stand_left':
        self.clip(self.left_states[0])
    if direction == 'stand_right':
        self.clip(self.right_states[0])
    if direction == 'stand_up':
        self.clip(self.up_states[0])
    if direction == 'stand_down':
        self.clip(self.down_states[0])

    self.image = self.sheet.subsurface(self.sheet.get_clip())

def handle_event(self, event):
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        game_over = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.update('left')
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.update('right')
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.update('up')
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.update('down')

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:  

        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.update('stand_left')            
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.update('stand_right')
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.update('stand_up')
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.update('stand_down')
```

Any ideas?  Im open to anything that will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities. A timer or a counter.

You could have a frameCounter multiplier that would case the sprite animation to change slower. This is not really flexible though, and depends on the amount of calls to update.

The better solution is to have a timer. If you add a parameter to update that would represent the amount of time that has passed since the last call, you can then store that in a variable. Having that you can change to the next frame every 50ms.

```
 def update(delta):
      self.frameTicks += delta
      if (self.frameTicks > 50):
          self.frameTicks = 0
          self.nextFrame()
```

Look into the Clock module of pygame for a way to get the time passed.

Apart from this, I would recommend to remove the clip operations completely, since they make your code much harder to read. In a small program like this, you can create a list of already cut subsurfaces, so the only thing that you will need to have is the current frame index.